# Room errors - how to fix them?

Tags: android, android-room

I'm using room for persistence on my android app and once I create my Database class I get the following errors:

- error: Entity class must be annotated with `@Entity`
- error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
- error: An entity must have at least 1 field annotated with `@PrimaryKey`

I narrowed it down to my Database class my eliminating everything else other than my Entity and `DAO` classes. I've tried everything I found online but nothing worked.

Here's the Entity class:

```
import android.arch.persistence.room.ColumnInfo;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Entity;
import android.arch.persistence.room.ForeignKey;
import android.arch.persistence.room.PrimaryKey;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

import static android.arch.persistence.room.ForeignKey.CASCADE;

@Entity
public class Character {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
public int characterId;

@ColumnInfo(name = "name")
public String name;

@ColumnInfo(name = "race")
public String race;

@ColumnInfo(name = "occupation")
public String occupation;

@ColumnInfo(name = "shadow")
public String shadow;

@ColumnInfo(name = "accurate")
public int accurate;

@ColumnInfo(name = "cunning")
public int cunning;

@ColumnInfo(name = "discreet")
public int discreet;

@ColumnInfo(name = "persuasive")
public int persuasive;

@ColumnInfo(name = "quick")
public int quick;

@ColumnInfo(name = "resolute")
public int resolute;

@ColumnInfo(name = "strong")
public int strong;

@ColumnInfo(name = "vigilant")
public int vigilant;

@ColumnInfo(name = "toughness")
public int toughness;

@ColumnInfo(name = "painThreshold")
public int painThreshold;

@ColumnInfo(name = "corruptionThreshold")
public int corruptionThreshold;

@ColumnInfo(name = "defense")
public int defense;

public int inventoryId;

public int spellBookId;

public Character() {

}

public Character(int characterId, String name, String race, String occupation, String shadow, int accurate, int cunning, int discreet, int persuasive, int quick, int resolute, int strong, int vigilant, int toughness, int painThreshold, int corruptionThreshold, int defense, int inventoryId, int spellBookId) {
    this.characterId = characterId;
    this.name = name;
    this.race = race;
    this.occupation = occupation;
    this.shadow = shadow;
    this.accurate = accurate;
    this.cunning = cunning;
    this.discreet = discreet;
    this.persuasive = persuasive;
    this.quick = quick;
    this.resolute = resolute;
    this.strong = strong;
    this.vigilant = vigilant;
    this.toughness = toughness;
    this.painThreshold = painThreshold;
    this.corruptionThreshold = corruptionThreshold;
    this.defense = defense;
    this.inventoryId = inventoryId;
    this.spellBookId = spellBookId;
}
...getters and setters
```

And this is the database class:

```
@Database (entities = {Character.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

public abstract CharDao charDao();
}
```

My DAO class:

```
@Dao
public interface CharDao {

@Insert
void addChar (Character character);

}
```

Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "symbhero.studio.com.symbhero"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0'
}
```

I really can't find out where I went wrong. I followed this [link](https://android.jlelse.eu/getting-started-with-room-persistence-library-8932276b4d8c) to set everything up.

All help appreciated!

Comment: you have to create two constructors one with without PrimaryKey

Comment: where is your dao class?

Comment: go through the tutorials of [android room database](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0)

Comment: Have you tried **clean project & rebuild project**?

Comment: I put the DAO now. I tried to clean and rebuild, no luck.

Comment: where are you creating your database object?

Comment: Hi, can you add your `build.gradle`. How do you include Android Room?

Answer (score 0):

maybe my inputs can help you :)

**Entity:**

1. List item

Missing table name:

```
@Entity(tableName = "your_tabel_name_here")
```

2. List item

Vars without column  info

```
public int inventoryId;

public int spellBookId;
```

3. List item

Ignore all except empty constructor

```
@Ignore

public Character(int characterId, String name, String race ...)
```

**DAO: **

1. First of all, name the Dao the same as the Entity: CharacterDAO
2. Use the following insert style:

   @Dao
   public interface CharacterDAO {

   ```
   @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
   void insertCharacter(Character... character);
   ```

   }

**App Database: **

```
@Database(entities = {Character.class},version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

    public abstract CharacterDAO characterDAO();
private static String DATABASE_NAME = "your_database_name";

    //https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.html
    public static synchronized AppDatabase getAppDatabase(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE =
                    Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                            .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine. But what I suppose is you might be importing different class instead of your `@Entity` Character in your `DAO` or `AppDatabase` classes.

Few coding tips would be.

- If you are defining same name in your `@ColumnInfo` as your field name, then there is no need for `@ColumnInfo` annotation.
- If you have `public` variables then you don't have to have setters and getters

Answer (score 0):

you have to check that all the classes [@Entity, @Dao, @Database] related to ROOM must be 
kept into same package. sometimes you need to delete build from app folder manually 
from explorer to rebuild the code.